# Empty document root in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, puphpet

I tried to set up a vagrant vm with `puphpet`. This worked so far. Everything is installed and the database and webserver are running now. I've also added a sync folder to the configuration (default one) `"./" -> "/var/www"`.

When I now ssh into the vagrant vm and list the content of the dir I see my folder content from the host file system. But if I open the vagrant vm through the IP address the webserver shows me an automatic generated index page with no files in the current folder.

Tried to change permissions with attaching this to the Vagrantfile sync folder configuration:

```
, :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
```

But nothing changed after `vagrant reload`. Still get empty automatic generated index page of apache2.

If I look into vagrant's `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` there is the following line:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
```

So is this probably the an issue? Or what else could be the problem?

Comment: sync folder option can't change any thing of httpd config file,　you should check your VM OS or the httpd version installed

Answer (score 0):

By default Apache creates an `index.html` page with the "It works!" message.

Check your webroot (`./`) and see if you can't find that file.